# Use avg of a count with another attribute in the same query

Tags: sql, group-by, count, average

I want to calculate the number of separate products sold per order each month with this command in SQL Developer, but it doesn't work. Please help.

```
SELECT  
    AVG(cnt) AS avg_reference,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM vente.jourliv), 'MM'), 'MONTH') AS month,
    idcommande
FROM
    (SELECT
         COUNT(idproduit) AS cnt,
         TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM vente.jourliv), 'MM'), 'MONTH'),
         idcommande    
     FROM
         vente)
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM vente.jourliv), 'MM'), 'MONTH'),  
    idcommande;
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: the result I want to have is the number of separate products sold per order"commande" each month based on a database where we have the idcommande as primary key and idproduct and the date in DD/MM/AAAA format